# Java JXLS - does the latest version 2.2.5 support more than 64k rows?

Tags: java, jxls

please does the latest version JXLS 2.2.5 support for more than 64k rows when exporting (transforming) data into pre-prepared xlsx template?

Thanks in advance,
ZP

Comment: The limitation to 64k rows isn't one caused by Jxls, but by the underlying library. As long as you use POI, and have enough memory, these big files will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use *jxls-poi* transformer and have a template in xlsx format you can have more than 64k rows in the final report